# Upgrading Pivotal HD to Pivotal/Hortonworks HDP

Tags: hadoop, upgrade, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

Given that Pivotal HD has been discontinued and Pivotal is now recommending an upgrade to Hortonworks HDP, I'm trying to understand the upgrade process. Since Pivotal HD uses Ambari as the manager, can we use the "usual" upgrade process as documented on the Hortonworks website (http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.2.1.0/bk_upgrading_Ambari/content/_ambari_upgrade_guide.html)

I tried looking for Pivotal HD to HDP upgrade documentation but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only upgrade from one version of HDP to another version of HDP. You can NOT upgrade Pivotal HD to HDP. This is evident by the information in the upgrade guide stating the upgrade strategies between HDP versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade from PHD to HDP but not through Ambari. Assuming you are using PHD 3.0, you can install HDP 2.2 liabraries. Once done upgrade using Ambari from 2.2. to HDP 2.4 and then HDP 2.6